# How does text in right-to-left languages work when writing HTML code?

Tags: html, text, unicode, notepad++, right-to-left

I am editing an HTML site that includes several paragraphs in Arabic, and something strange is happening when I delete or replace existing words.  If I place a cursor in the middle of a paragraph and press backspace to delete a word `letter-by-letter`, sometimes the cursor moves left and deletes letters to the left of the cursor (as should be expected with a right-to-left language), but after the first word is deleted, the cursor starts moving right and deletes the word on the right. Other times it happens ***vice versa--right first, then left***.

I don't speak Arabic (using Google translate to replace outdated text), but I am still puzzled by this behavior.

Additionally, if I select a single word and paste another word into the selection, the entire line moves, and it's obvious than more than the word I selected has been replaced.  I can verify that something is wrong because when I copy the resulting text  into Google Translate, it stops making grammatical sense.

Are there special rules I need to follow when editing `right-to-left` text in HTML files?  I am using Notepad++.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is all down to the editor. That said, does it happen with files in any other language? Does it happen in any other editor?

Comment: Have you looked into how the CSS attribute: "direction: rtl;" works? It works on block-level elements, so I can imagine what you're seeing is changes from in-line elements to block level elements when the direction changes.

Comment: @David The change I'm making are intra-div, so I don't see how that explains the cursor behavior.  It also doesn't explain the most puzzling part, which is that sometimes the Backspace button deletes to the left and other times to the right, all while in the same paragraph.

Comment: What I mean is that by marking some content within a div as a different direction, I think it would create a new block level element. To give any feedback or advice that's more detailed, you'll need to post more information, like the actual HTML and changes you're making to it. I'm not even quite sure if you're talking about an HTML problem or a Notepad++ problem.

Comment: How could it mark content as a different direction if I didn't introduce any new code that would set the direction?

Comment: You may be having an editor problem. Many editors does not work properly with `RTL` languages. Especially when editing a text. Try editing `Arabic` text separately than `English` text or even `HTML` codes. In `Notepad` you can press `right ctrl + shift' so notepad is showed entirely in right-to-left then text editing will be so easier. At end can you paste your code here?

Comment: Thank you for the tip!  This is Notepad++, not the default Windows Notepad.  I will try a different editor though, thanks!